# XSL Transform C# - Root Element Missing

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transform

Long time reader first time poster!

My question is relatively straight forward...

Source XML: http://pastebin.com/xHnv20Ej
XSLT: http://pastebin.com/bAk6sZ9V

I'm trying to transform the XML using the XSLT.
All the editors i have used have verified that both files are formatted correctly and transformation is successful.

As soon as i use the XslTransform class in C#, i get a "Root Element Is Missing" Exception.

```
XslTransform myXslTransform;
myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
myXslTransform.Load(Utility.getTransformerToUse());
myXslTransform.Transform(fullPath, targetFile);
```

As far as I can see, all root elements are present and no other transformer has this issue. Is there something I am missing with regards to C#'s XSLTransform class?

Many thanks.

Comment: +1 for clearly defined question and code examples! Oh and welcome to SO!

Comment: Can you please post the code for `Utility.getTransformerToUse()`?

Comment: I've doubly-verified that Microsoft has no issue with your XML.  The [output from Visual Studio passing your XML through the XSLT](http://pastebin.com/8BMYH7iY)

Comment: The issue is in the code that you haven't shown to us -- the Utility class.

Comment: The Utility.getTransformerToUse() simply returns a String with the path of the xsl file, its a static method and the path is set earlier when searching for transformer files.

Comment: I've created a fresh application that just uses the transformer and the transformation works fine so i'm assuming the issue is due to an XMLReader or some other function being called before the XMLTransform causing the issue.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! - The XML file was being malformed by an XMLValidatingReader before it was transformed!
Thankyou for all the replies and sorry that the solution probably won't ever help anyone.. lol.

Comment: Just a comment irrelevant to your problem but important on the API use, Microsoft's XSLT 1.0 processor in the .NET framework since .NET 2.0 is `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`, `XslTransform` is obsolete since .NET 2.0. So unless you use .NET 1.x you should move to `XslCompiledTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED! - The XML file was being malformed by an XMLValidatingReader before it was transformed! Thankyou for all the replies and sorry that the solution probably won't ever help anyone.. lol.